# Running "PackageManagerTroubeShootingProcedure"

Tags: muon-package-manager

From searching the solution for bugs I encountered, I ended up on this page

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure

I want to know under which conditions it is likely to follow this procedure.

Comment: Generally, use that guide if you think you have discovered a bug in a package manager. Most of the time, it's not a reportable bug after all. Most package manager errors are due to unwise decsions by the user to override or bypass or ignore the package manager, to install wrong-version packages, or simple misunderstanding about what the packe manager does/doesn't do. Usually the output provides excellent clues about exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @user535733  <br/> **Thank you** for answering this for me. <br/> Extremely sorry for replying late